# Reading to and from arrays in Assembly?

Tags: string, assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I'm having a bit of trouble reading to and from arrays in assembly.

It's a fairly simple program (albeit at this point, far from finished). All I'm trying to do at this point is read a string of (what we're assuming is numbers), converting it to a decimal number, and printing it. Here's what I've got so far. As of now, it prints str1. After you enter a number and hit enter, it prints str1 again and freezes. Can anyone offer some insight as to what all I'm doing wrong?

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data

buffersize equ 80
buffer DWORD buffersize DUP (0)

str1 BYTE "Enter numbers to be added together. Press (Q) to Quit.", 0dh, 0ah,0;
str2 BYTE "The numbers entered were: ", 0dh, 0ah, 0
str3 BYTE "The total of numbers entered is: ", 0dh, 0ah, 0
error BYTE "Invalid Entry. Please try again.", 0dh, 0ah,0
value DWORD 0

.code
main PROC
mov edx, OFFSET str1
call Writestring

Input:
 call readstring
 mov buffer[edi], eax

 cmp buffer[edi], 0
 JL NOTDIGIT
 cmp buffer[edi], 9
 JG NOTDIGIT

call cvtDec
mov edx, buffer[edi]
call WriteString
jmp endloop

Notdigit:
 mov edx, OFFSET error
 call writestring
 exit

 cvtDec:
    mov eax, buffer[edi]
    AND eax,0Fh
    mov buffer[edi],edx
    ret

endloop:
main ENDP
END MAIN
```

Comment: Please try debugging, step by step.

Answer (score 0):

First off, Mr. Irvine created the function called `WriteString`, but you use 2 variations - writestring and  Writestring; you do use the correct case of the function in one place.  Get into the habit of using the correct names of functions now, and it will cut down on bugs later.

Second, you created a label called `Notdigit` but yet you use `JL      NOTDIGIT` and `JG      NOTDIGIT` in your code.  Again, use the correct spelling.  MASM should of given you an A2006 error "undefined symbol"

You also declared your entry point as `main`, but you close your code section with `END MAIN` instead of `END main`.

If you have MASM set up properly (by adding `option casemap:none` at the top of your source.  Or just open irvine32.inc and uncomment the line that says `OPTION CASEMAP:NONE`)

Let's look at the `ReadString` procedure comment in irvine32.asm:

```
; Reads a string from the keyboard and places the characters
; in a buffer.
; Receives: EDX offset of the input buffer
;           ECX = maximum characters to input (including terminal null)
; Returns:  EAX = size of the input string.
; Comments: Stops when Enter key (0Dh,0Ah) is pressed. If the user
; types more characters than (ECX-1), the excess characters
; are ignored.
```

`ReadString` takes an address of the buffer to hold the inputed string in `edx`, you are using the address of your prompt `str1`, maybe you meant to use `buffer`?  You also did not put the size of the buffer into `ecx`

Your using `edi` as an index into your buffer, what value does `edi` contain?  Your trying to put the value of `eax` into it, what does `eax` contain???  Both `edi` and `eax` probably contain garbage; not what you want.

Look at this carefully:

```
cvtDec:
    mov     eax, buffer[edi]
    AND     eax,0Fh
    mov     buffer[edi],edx
```

Your putting a value (That you think is an ASCII value of a number) into `eax` then converting to a decimal value... ok...  Next, you are putting whatever is in `edx` back into your buffer.  Is that what you want?